# If $R$ is Noetherian, show that any element of the form $x-a$, $a\in R$ is a nonzerodivisor in $R[[x]]$

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity, assume $R$ is Noetherian, show that any element of the form $x-a$, $a\in R$ is a nonzerodivisor in $R[[x]]$

I can prove this by flatness of completion. I wonder if we can just use basic properties of Noetherian rings to prove the claim ?

Comment: Could $x-a$ be a zero divisor in $R[[x]]$ if $R$ is not Noetherian?

Comment: Believe it or not, this can really happen. An example can be found in Fields' paper ZERO DIVISORS AND NILPOTENT ELEMENTS IN POWER SERIES RINGS.

Comment: @user26857 To be clear "this can really happen" refers to the failure of the statement when $R$ is not Noetherian?

Comment: @rschwieb Yes, of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very easy. Let $f\in R[[x]]$ such that $(x-a)f=0$ and $f\ne0$. Write $f=a_0+a_1x+\cdots$. We may assume $a_0\ne0$. From $(x-a)f=0$ we get $aa_0=0$, $aa_1=a_0$, $aa_2=a_1$, and so on. Now notice that $a^{i+1}a_{i}=0$ for all $i\ge0$. Since $R$ is noetherian, the ideal generated by all coefficients of $f$ is finitely generated, hence there exists $p\ge1$ such that $a^pa_i=0$ for all $i\ge0$. From $a^pa_p=0$ and $aa_{p}=a_{p-1}$ we get $a^{p-1}a_{p-1}=0$. Then, from  $a^{p-1}a_{p-1}=0$ and $aa_{p-1}=a_{p-2}$ we get $a^{p-2}a_{p-2}=0$. Continuing this way we get $a_0=0$, a contradiction.